# Dualboot windows and ubuntu, where to install bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I've got a new ssd and would like to install ubuntu on it and dual-boot it on my main machine with windows. I have two drives beyond the new one, 1 ssd and 1 hdd, with mbr partitions. Windows is installed on the ssd. (ssd is primary partition and boot drive, BIOS mode: legacy)

Everything is working and both windows and the ubuntu installation media finds the new drive. Now my question is: which drive do I install the boot loader on? I would like to be able to choose which system to load at boot.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Your machine firmware has control over which drive will be read looking for the boot loader; so the correct drive is which ever you've chosen via BIOS/uEFI settings, or if it's not a setting you control (*rare, but possible being machine specific*), it's set to which ever drive the BIOS will use to boot.  We can't know as it's machine specific (firmware rather than hardware).

Comment: You can put the boot loader just about any where you want, even on a USB drive. If you put it on the Windows disk it will overwrite the Windows bootloader, which is not bad. If Windows boots Legacy, Ubuntu and the new bootloader should also boot legacy. I would suggest installing Ubuntu in Legacy mode using the Something option and put GRUB on the Ubuntu Disk. It will add Windows to the boot menu automatically, If it does not for some reason, just run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: With multiple drives only use the Something Else install option, & that gives you the option of which drive (not partition) to install grub2 boot loader into. All other options (& UEFI ) only install grub to first drive,  which you do not want.

Comment: thank you all for your answers!

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I followed your instruction and it worked perfectly, thanks! I can mark it as answer if you post it as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, Answer has been added below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Where to Install Bootloader

You can put the boot loader just about any where you want, even on a USB drive.

If you put it on the Windows disk it will overwrite the Windows bootloader, which is not bad, unless you decide to remove Ubuntu.

If Windows boots Legacy, Ubuntu and the new bootloader should also boot legacy. For GRUB to work with all OS they all need to be installed in same BIOS/UEFI mode.

I would suggest installing Ubuntu in Legacy mode using the `Something else` option and put GRUB on the Ubuntu Disk. It will add Windows to the boot menu automatically, If it does not for some reason, just run sudo update-grub

Answer (score 1):

Boot loader will be installed during Ubuntu installation. I sugest install boot loader (Grub) to MBR of hardrive where Windows is installed. If you are using EFI system partion, also use the same hard drive. You can turn off the Security Boot in BIOS before start Ubuntu installation. Some third-party drivers (e.g. wifi) can be not installed properly. Grub boot menu will be created automatically. Good luck.

Comment: As I stated in the question I have Legacy (BIOS) and not UEFI. Thank you for your answer!